# Extract JSON from HTTP response received as text

Tags: json, ionic4, laravel-8

I am testing login/registration between ionic 4 and Laravel api but having trouble with the response to the apps HTTP POST's. Initially I had trouble with the response because it returned header information with the JSON response

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<!--
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/file-manager/js/file-manager.js') }}"></script>
-->
{"message":"Successfully created user!"}
```

I resolved this by setting

```
responseType: 'text'
```

in the HTTP POST options. But my problem is I still need to extract the JSON from the response. How can I accomplish this?

Currently using this post script for ionic

```
  register(name: String,  email: String, password: String) 
  { 
    this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/register', {name: name, email: email, password: password},{responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe((data : any) =>  {
        console.log(data)
       });
       
  }
```

And for the response from the server

```
<?php
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
    ], 201);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this for now by switching from laravel 8 to 5.7.